# Problems with iPhone and sqlite query

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I get the following error when I try to run my program. Any reasons why I get it? I have tried for several hours now but I give up. THANKS!

Error:

2011-03-08 19:18:29.967 iphoneApp[2561:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString'

```
- (AnswerDTO *)findAnswerById:(NSInteger)primary_key {
    AnswerDTO *dto = [[[AnswerDTO alloc] init] autorelease];

    sqlite3_stmt *statement = nil;
    const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM klb_answers WHERE id = 7;";

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) { 
        sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, primary_key);

        NSInteger answerId = sqlite3_column_int(statement, ANSWER_ID);
        NSInteger answerQuestionId = sqlite3_column_int(statement, ANSWER_QUESTION_ID);
        NSString *answerDescription = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, ANSWER_DESCRIPTION)];
        NSString *answerSerialNumber = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, ANSWER_SERIAL_NUMBER)];
        NSInteger answerIsCorrect = sqlite3_column_int(statement, ANSWER_IS_CORRECT);

        dto.answerID = answerId;
        dto.questionID = answerQuestionId;
        dto.description = answerDescription;
        dto.serialNumber = answerSerialNumber;

        if (answerIsCorrect == 0) {
            dto.isCorrect = NO;
        } else {
            dto.isCorrect = YES;
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Noe feil med statementet");
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);

    return dto;
}
```

Comment: Only masochists use the SQLite C API in Objective-C.  [Use FMDB](http://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) or [CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are "running" your query.  You prepared it and bound your params but you never ran sqlite3_step() to execute the query and get the response.  Even if it is a single record or a scalar.

As a result, your column functions returning null values.

Comment: You are welcome.  Happened to me on my first sqlite project ... happens to me every time.  Might I suggest using Core Data for database persistence?  Or maybe even one of the many wrappers for sqlite (TouchSQL, etc.)?  Makes it more object-oriented.  However, nothing beats learning the hard(-er) way the first time to get respect for the frameworks :)